# Passing session data to templates without customizing views

Tags: python, django, templates, registration

I'm working on adding subscriptions using `django-registration`. Right now, I'm trying to create a Paypal form on the `registration_complete` page.

I have created a session variable as follows:

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        form = RegistrationFormEx(data=request.POST)
        new_user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        digest=hmac.new(str(request.POST['username'])+str(request.POST['password1']), str(request.POST['password1']),hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
        new_profile = UserProfile(user=new_user,api_key=digest)
        new_profile.save()
        #now add other fields including password hash as well

        uid = new_profile.id
        #Add username to session to pass it via Paypal later
        request.session['username']=request.POST['username']
        merchant_profile = MerchantProfile(user_id=uid,
            create_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
            modified_time=datetime.datetime.now(),
            payment_card_id=uid,
            current_state=1,
            name=request.POST['name'],
             )
        merchant_profile.save()

        return new_user

    user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

My template for the Paypal form is is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<p>
    {% trans "You are now registered. Activation email sent." %}

<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sumit_1349250468_per@sample.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="registration charge {{ request.session.username }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://url/payment_result?response=success">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://url/sorry">

</form>

</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Without changing any views, how can I print the value for `request.session.username` in this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings.py, `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` should include [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) - This makes the `request` variable available to your templates.

Although, a word of warning: When the user activates his email and signs in after returning, the session variable will probably have changed.